# How to create a customized stdheader (not .h file)?

Tags: c, vim, sublimetext3

did some searching but most answers pertain to .h files.

During a recent code camp, we were able to add customized header in vim by :stdheader. The header automatically includes file name / author name / creation time / update time. Can anyone point me to the right direction in generating my own stdheader template?

Here is the sample from github (line 1 to line 11), thanks!

https://github.com/sebastiencs/piscine_42/blob/master/j02/ex01/ft_print_reverse_alphabet.c

Comment: Is there anything wrong with storing a template and then simply `:r templatename`, which you can then automate with a key map?

Comment: That's what the "snippets" plugins are for.  There are many of those, my personal preference for Vim is to use [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) with the [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets) set of snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a template expander plugin. There are many. Some are more or less advanced. There are a [couple of grids](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template#see-also), and a [Q/A on vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-snippets-plugins)  that try to compare them, but unfortunately nothing really exhaustive.

Template expansion can be automated on the creation of a new file, or triggered manually (for snippets). It depends on each plugin. It starts with `:h template` (solution that won't update automatically dates, names, and so on), and it goes far with those plugins.

In [mu-template](https://github.com/LucHermitte/mu-template#c--c) (and by extension in [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/snippets.md#cppbase-class-non-virtual) regarding C and C++), you'll be able to have several levels of customisation regarding new file: you can customize the file headers, the anti-reinclusion guard naming policy, request for a namespace (in C++ case), etc?

PS: your question in actually an [exact duplicate](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6358/how-do-i-add-skeleton-text-to-new-vim-files/) of this question on vi.SE (and probably a few other questions here)