# Configure vim to add module declaration for haskell files

Tags: haskell, vim

When I edit a new Haskell file e.g. "xyz.hs", I'd like vim to automatically add

```
module Xyz where
```

at the first line. How can it be configured?

Comment: Excellent idea, I need to look up the corresponding action for Emacs.

Comment: @leftaroundabout added the corresponding emacs plugin

Comment: IMO, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315386/how-to-create-a-customized-stdheader-not-h-file -- or the other way around. I let others (i.e, you) chose to vote or not (I have too many points, and my votes are kind of not democratic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like

```
au BufNewFile *.hs call WriteHaskellModuleHeader(expand('%:t:r'))

function! WriteHaskellModuleHeader(fname)
    execute "normal imodule " . a:fname . " where\n"
endfunction
```

in your .vimrc for starters; But of course that breaks the moment you use hierarchical modules (in which case a general vimscript only solution wouldn't work anymore, you'd probably have to invoke cabal or something to find your source roots, and the whole thing would probably get fairly messy very quickly).

---

Opinion: It doesn't seem to me like something particularly worthwhile, it's not a lot of text to write and you don't write it often.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a snippet engine like [Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) together with [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/) you can trigger the keyword `module` to get the desired result.

See https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/haskell.snippets#L43 for the line responsible for this.

### Edit:

For emacs one choice would be [yasnippets](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/): and the module keyword is supported in
[yasnippet-snippets](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/blob/9ce0b05f4b4d693831e67dd65d660716a8192e8d/haskell-mode/module)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like it to be automatic, without having to write `module`.

Comment: As @cubic said i don't think not typing `module` is the killer feature, but the snippets give you way more than just this, for example i have the boilerplate for generating my test suite in one snippet,  as well as language pragmas and import statements. If you are not already using it, try it for 10 days, i think it is at least worth trying